# Get Google drive video embed code using api

Tags: php, video, iframe, google-drive-api, embed

Hello everyone,

I was working on a project where i need to display a video specifically from my google drive on a webpage. I don't want to manually select the video and copy its embed code, is there a way we can obtain the embed code for a video using google api (PHP preferred) ?

So that i can use this code within an iframe and display the video.

Please also suggest if there are other ways.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can start with Google Drive API https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/php and this segment of code i hope can help you.

```
<?php 
// New Google Client, see all settings at link in description
$client = new Google_Client();

// New Google Drive Service
$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

// Params with filter of MIME type for search only videos mp4 (you can change this)
$optParams = [
  'q' => "mimeType='video/mp4'",
  'pageSize' => 10,
  'fields' => 'nextPageToken, files(id, name, webViewLink)'
]; 

// Get files from our request
$files = $service->files->listFiles($optParams);

// Print an iframe for each video
foreach($files->files as $file){
    // Now I need to make a little detail about the next lines of code so look at [Info]
    $src = str_replace('/view', '/preview', $file->webViewLink);
    echo '<iframe width="500" height="200" target="_parent" src="'. $src .'"></iframe>'
}
?>
```

**[Info]**

The objects returned from `$service->files->listFiles($optParams)` are [Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/php/latest/class-Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile.html) objects and each of these have a series of properties. From v3 of Google API a properties called `embedLink` was removed and there isn't an alternative for this property from v2([Migrate to Google Drive API v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/migration)) so as you seen in my code i use webViewLink property that return a URL to a view of file like this:

```
https://drive.google.com/file/d/123456789/view
```

But if you use this URL inside an `<iframe>` the browser notice to you an error:

```
Refused to display 'https://drive.google.com/file/d/123456789/view' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.`
```

I'm not holding you too much on this issue and there are a [lot of question](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=X-frame-Options) about this. So we need to request a preview of file and not a view an i do that with

`str_replace('/view', '/preview', $file->webViewLink);`

on the URL returned by the request. Now you can use this URL in a `<iframe>`

Comment: Thank you for the answer @alvarofvr , It really did help a lot to figure out. My code was a little bit different from this any way i was able to print all the response from $files. And as a surprise embedlink was one of the result which i needed exactly.