# Having to click two play buttons to start the video in google drive

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I have a situation here were I got to click two play buttons on an google drive video embed

This is my code for showing the video

```
<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/video_id/preview" width="960" height="540" allowfullscreen="true"></iframe>
```

After the video is loaded it displays a video thumbnail with play button and then when I click on it, it goes to another play button with a youtube like interface.

How can I get rid of this two play button? I just need one click then video should play after.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43214124/how-to-play-video-from-google-drive-using-javascript) on how to play video from Drive using JavaScript. It stated that Google provides some GET-params like export and id with google-drive to give you the ability to insert an uploaded video into a HTML5-video-tag.

> ```
> $("#play").click(function() {
>    $("#video")[0].play();
> });
> ```

> ```
> <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
>
> <button id="play" style="margin-top: 300px;">Play</button>
>
> <video id="video" width="320" height="240" controls>
>    <source src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B8-qLYDzDfCyRF9vOE9sWmx5YjA" type='video/mp4'>
>    Your browser does not support the video tag.
> </video>
> ```

Check this link for additional information: [Get Google drive video embed code using api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47509128/get-google-drive-video-embed-code-using-api)